# How can I save the playerprefs of a boolean variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to code a mute button, and it works, however the setting of that button is not saved.

```
public void Mute (){
    AudioListener.volume = 0;
    sound.enabled = false;
    sound.image.enabled = false;
    noSound.enabled = true;
    noSound.image.enabled = true;
}

public void UnMute (){
    AudioListener.volume = 1;
    sound.enabled = true;
    sound.image.enabled = true;
    noSound.enabled = false;
    noSound.image.enabled = false;
}
```

I have 2 methods here, and I need it to save the state of which one was clicked `using playerprefs`. I was thinking something along the lines of a boolean, but I'm stumped, and and I can't wrap my head around how I would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that with the help of a boolean variable as like the following:

```
public bool isMuted = false;
public void Do_muteOperation()
        {
            if (isMuted)
            {
                UnMute();
                isMuted = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Mute();
                isMuted = true;
            }
        }
```